# Weblogic Deployment Issues with Jackson.databind exception

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jackson, weblogic12c

How can I resolve jackson databind error when deploying a .war spring boot app built on java 11, Apache spark 3.0.1, and scala 2.12.10 on weblogic 12c server. I keep getting this deployment error even after adding jackson databind version 2.11.4 maven dependency to the pom file.

PS: Scala was not installed on the deployment server since the compilation was successful during development

> weblogic.application.ModuleException:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Scala module
> 2.11.4 requires Jackson Databind version >= 2.11.0 and < 2.12.0

Kindly see below the stack trace from the log

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Scala module 2.11.4 requires Jackson Databind version >= 2.11.0 and < 2.12.0
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:61)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule.setupModule$(JacksonModule.scala:46)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:17)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:751)
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.JacksonMessageWriter.<init>(JacksonMessageWriter.scala:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:272)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:366)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ProviderToService.apply(ProviderToService.java:58)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ProviderToService.apply(ProviderToService.java:54)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:799)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:343)
    at java.util.LinkedHashSet.<init>(LinkedHashSet.java:169)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Sets.newLinkedHashSet(Sets.java:325)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getClasses(Providers.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getCustomProviders(Providers.java:202)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.<init>(MessageBodyFactory.java:247)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:272)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:366)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:777)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:740)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:710)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.<init>(ComponentModelValidator.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:549)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:356)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:307)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:99)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:87)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:74)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:31)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:676)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:615)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:2072)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:2049)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1938)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3191)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1864)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:919)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
    at weblogic.d>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue when I upgrade the Jersey version from 1.x to 2.x.

**Technical reason behind the issue:**

If you have `org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson` in the classpath, then Jersey CDI registers `DefaultJacksonJaxbJsonProvider` resource for the Json handling functionalities such as `MessageBodyReader, MessageBodyWriter`. Because of `DefaultJacksonJaxbJsonProvider` intialization which underlyingly registers scala module `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule` causes the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Scala module` issue.

**Solution:**

We can override the default `DefaultJacksonJaxbJsonProvider` functionalities with the following steps:

1. Add the following dependency to your classpath

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider', version: '2.11.1'
```

2. Add `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json` package under the radar of Jersey CDI resources scan using `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` as below

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>
        com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json
    <param-value>
</init-param>
```

Because of the above declaration in web.xml, `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` will be injected as JsonProvider which will take care of the JSON handling functionalities such as `MessageBodyReader, MessageBodyWriter` part.

**Optional Steps:**

1. Remove the `org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-binding` dependency, if you have in the classpath
2. Remove `com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.*` from the classpath or if it comes as the transitive dependency. For instance, in my use case, `com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.10` dependency is pulled to the classpath as a transitive dependency through `com.wordnik:swagger-core_2.*` and I upgraded the `com.wordnik` swagger to the `io.springfox` swagger.

**Note:**

This solution is applicable to any app servers like `Wildfly/JBOSS EAP/WebLogic/ Websphere` because this issue is purely related to `Jersey 2.x`

Comment: Thank you Prasanth. This is quite helpful